# How to set the position when you create a dijit.tooltipdialog.

Tags: javascript, position, tooltip, dojo

As the title, I don't know how to set the position dijit.tooltipdialog which relative the Dom, does it use "orient()"? but how to set the parameters of orient(). if not use orient(), could you please tell me which one I should use. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

orient (string[]):

When placing a pop-up around a DOM node, it is possible to specify where the pop-up should appear around it by providing an array of position strings. Dijit will try each position in order until the pop-up appears fully within the viewport. Possible values are:

- before: places drop down to the left of the anchor node/widget, or to the right in the case of RTL scripts like Hebrew and Arabic; aligns either the top of the drop down with the top of the anchor, or the bottom of the drop down with bottom of the anchor.
- after: places drop down to the right of the anchor node/widget, or to the left in the case of RTL scripts like Hebrew and Arabic; aligns either the top of the drop down with the top of the anchor, or the bottom of the drop down with bottom of the anchor.
- before-centered: centers drop down to the left of the anchor node/widget, or to the right in the case of RTL scripts like Hebrew and Arabic
- after-centered: centers drop down to the right of the anchor node/widget, or to the left in the case of RTL scripts like Hebrew and Arabic
- above-centered: drop down is centered above anchor node
- above: drop down goes above anchor node, left sides aligned
- above-alt: drop down goes above anchor node, right sides aligned
- below-centered: drop down is centered above anchor node
- below: drop down goes below anchor node
- below-alt: drop down goes below anchor node, right sides aligned

If left undefined, the default value is [ "below", "below-alt", "above", "above-alt" ].

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/popup.html